# Python: passing a function as a parameter while in a class

Tags: python, class, matplotlib, parameters, rules

I'm currently using the FuncAnimation function of matplotlib and encountered an issue. My code follows a similar logic to the code below

```
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fig = plt.figure()
    def update(self, num):
        print("This is getting called")
    def animate(self):
        ani = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, update, interval=100)

def main():
    obj = Example()
    obj.animate()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

At the moment, my code doesn't print out "This is getting called". I tried passing in self.update instead of update into FuncAnimation, to no avail. I also tried writing global update before calling FuncAnimation, which also doesn't work. I'm wondering if anybody can help me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer by @ReblochonMasque is correct in saying that you need to actually show the figure, using `plt.show()`.

You do however not need to return anything from the animating function (unless you want to use blitting, in which case you would need to return an iterable of `Artists` to blit).
And also, if you make your `FuncAnimation` a class variable (`self.ani`) it ensures to be able to call `show()` at any point, not just within the `animate function.

```
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()

    def update(self, i):
        print("This is getting called {}".format(i))
        self.ax.plot([i,i+1],[i,i+2])

    def animate(self):
        self.ani = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.update, interval=100)


def main():
    obj = Example()
    obj.animate()
    plt.show()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

Your animate(self) method must return a tuple.
You also need to show the plot.

```
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        self.fig = plt.figure()

    def update(self, num):
        print(f"This is getting called {num}")
        return num,

    def animate(self):
        ani = animation.FuncAnimation(self.fig, self.update, interval=100)
        plt.show()


def main():
    obj = Example()
    obj.animate()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: There is no need to return anything from `update` in this case. Returning `num` however does not make any sense, either return an iterable of `matplotlib.artist.Artist`s or nothing, but not some random thing. The main point is really to actually show the plot. I would further advise to make `ani` a class variable, which allows to call `plt.show()` also outside of the instance method.

Comment: Maybe that wasn't clear. I provided another answer to show what I meant here.

Comment: Cool - your answer is better than mine; I upvoted it, and the OP should accept it.